# How do I Echo a variable in html?

Tags: php, html, if-statement, echo

I'm trying to include a variable within some existing code but my PHP skills are quite basic. I've looked around and can;t find anything I can reaidly apply as a fix for this although I'm sure it's pretty simple.

The original code is:

```
<p class="ad-price"><?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true)) cp_get_price_legacy($post->ID); else cp_get_price($post->ID); ?></p>
```

and the code I'm trying to change it to (and think should be working) is:

```
<?php $yourtext = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_pricing_period', TRUE); 
echo "<p class="ad-price"><?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true)) cp_get_price_legacy($post->ID); else cp_get_price($post->ID); ?> $yourtext</p>"; ?>
```

These changes are obviously wrong because it stops the whole file working. Can anyone shed light on where I'm getting this wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the double quotes in your html

```
echo "<p class=\"ad-price\"><?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true)) cp_get_price_legacy($post->ID); else cp_get_price($post->ID); ?> $yourtext</p>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have some syntax error (quotes not escaped and tags wrongly opend/closed). As a sidenote, "expanding" brackets makes your code more readable and it's easier to spot errors.

```
<?php
$yourtext = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_pricing_period', TRUE); 

echo "<p class=\"ad-price\">";
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true)) 
{
 cp_get_price_legacy($post->ID);
}
else 
{
  cp_get_price($post->ID); 
}

echo $yourtext."</p>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems. One, you've got mis-matched quotes within your echo statement:

```
echo "<p class="ad-price"><?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true))  etc....
               ^-here   ^--here
```

PHP will see those extra quotes as terminating the string, and then wonder what this `ad-price` directive is. This'll be a syntax error.

As well, once you get the string sorted out by escaping the embedded quotes:

```
echo "<p class=\"ad-price\">etc...."
```

you'll still end up with this not working. PHP will **NOT** see the `<?php ... ?>` within the string as PHP code to execute. it's within a string, so it'll be treated as part of the string and the PHP code will be echoed out to the user. In this case, you'd probably have write the whole thing more like this:

```
echo '<p class="ad-price">';
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true)) {
     echo cp_get_price_legacy($post->ID);
} else { 
     echo cp_get_price($post->ID);
}
echo " $yourtext</p>";
```

Comment: Thanks Marc B. That worked perfectly (once I remebered to close the PHP statement with ?> that is)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put backslashes before the quotation marks in this statement:

```
echo "<p class="ad-price"><?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true))          cp_get_price_legacy($post->ID); else cp_get_price($post->ID); ?> $yourtext</p>"; ?>
```